# How to replace browser back button on cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9

i am working on a product page with lots of selections. (they are required by industry, so i can't really remove them)

About every 5th customer makes the needed selections, and then presses "add to cart" - and than goes back to product page to change smng.

We've added "Change product options" button which brings them back to product pages with their selections saved, so they can change options easily without needing to select everything again - the page url looks like this **ourmagentostore.com/checkout/cart/configure/id/5231/**

However some people still click back button in browser, and it brings them to **ourmagentostore.com/product-name** - it's not saving any selections, so they have to start over again, and some people give up at this point.

How i can replace the browser back button on cart page with checkout/cart/configure/id/XXXX/ ?

I know it's possible with js, but is there a better way to do it?